# How can I change the format of just one sheet of an excel workbook using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have large excel files with format .xlsb and .xlsx. I need to read only one sheet from all these files in python. It takes forever to use read_excel on these files. I want to save off that sheet I need as a .csv file and then read it to make it quicker. The only problem is that I have 24 of these excel workbooks and I don't have the time to manually take that sheet for each workbook and save it as .csv. Any suggestions on how I can change the format of just that one sheet?

Answer (score 0):

An .xlsx-file is technically a folder. It is possible to open it as a zip-file and extract the individual sheets. However, I have never attempted to do this using Python, so I do not know how easy it is to do.
[image: Excel zip-folder]